# Java error: cannot find symbol, but everything is in the same package

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javac

I'm having issues running a java class through the command line.
It runs perfectly fine through the IntelliJ IDE, but when I attempt to compile my Simulator class, it throws an error

```
Simulator.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
    private final StackCreator<String> myStack;
                  ^
  symbol:   class StackCreator
  location: class Simulator
Simulator.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        myStack = new StackCreator<>();
                      ^
  symbol:   class StackCreator
  location: class Simulator
2 errors
error: compilation failed
```

StackCreator and Simulator both have "package JavaClasses;" at the start of the files.
I've tried compiling StackCreator first and it works, but doesn't change anything for Simulator, still producing the same error.

Comment: "but when I attempt to compile my Simulator class" please show the command line for javac.

Comment: @AndyTurner It's already in the post?

Comment: Where? I'm looking for something like `javac Simulator.java`. You need to make sure that either you're compiling the two files at the same time (e.g. `javac Simulator.java StackCreator.java`), or you've got a pre-compiled version of the `StackCreator` class on the compiler's classpath. This works in your IDE because the IDE will "just do" things like this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javac isn't going to scan your entire disk, you need to tell it *everything*. There is a reason nobody* ever actually invokes `javac`, ever. They run `mvn`, `gradle`, or have set up a CI tool to do so, or let their IDE do so.

If you must use javac for some bizarre reason (do yourself a favour and learn first steps maven, it's really not very difficult and avoids this mess), you need to tell it where to look. There are multiple ways to do so:

Let's assume you have these files:

```
/Users/zekrofire/projects/MyApp/src/StackCreator/MyApp.java
/Users/zekrofire/projects/MyApp/src/StackCreator/util/MyFastList.java
/Users/zekrofire/projects/MyApp/src/otherpkg/Something.java
```

and you want the class files to be in `/Users/zekrofire/projects/MyApp/bin`.

### Easiest way: Compile all the things, in one go

Forget about a `src` dir and mix your java and class files (if you find this ugly, see comment about using maven). Then, just...

`javac *.java`

This will fix your problem. Tell javac about EVERY source file. Unfortunately, you can't java to just recursively trawl an entire dir for every java file, you'd have to do:

```
cd /Users/zekrofire/projects/MyApp
cd src
mv -r * ..
cd ..
rmdir src
javac StackCreator/*.java otherPkg/*.java StackCreator/util/*.java
```

### Use -classpath

```
cd /Users/zekrofire/projects/MyApp
javac -cp bin -d bin src/StackCreator/*.java
```

now you can compile files one at a time.

### Use -sourcepath

This isn't as cool as it sounds, don't think this lets you skip using an actual build system.

```
cd /Users/zekrofire/projects/MyApp
javac -sourcepath src -d bin src/StackCreator/*.java
```

### The absolute, hands down best way

```
apt install maven
; create a pom.xml file describing your deps
; move your source files to src/main/java as per
; maven standard
mvn compile
```

*) I rounded down.